# Deploy Files after build jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I was abled to build with jenkins on a Build Server and was able to get the publish files on local. 
However, I am unable to deploy these to a diferrent application server when I specify the path '\192.168.1.51\MyPublishedFiles' in the publish profile.
This is probably because the app server uses login credentials. 
I have the login credentials but cannot find a plugin which can help me copy the files to another server.
What strategy / Plugin can I use do to the same ?

Comment: what platform do you use on your build server?

Comment: Windows server 2012,

Comment: I assume you use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ArtifactDeployer+Plugin ? Have you setup your credentials in global Jenkins credentials configuration? This can be accessed from Jenkins main page from menu list on the left side. For it to appear you need https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin

Comment: I just need to paste the published files on the filesstem of the sever, should I give 192.168.1.51\MyPublishedFiles in the hostname ?

Comment: try `\\192.168.1.51\MyPublishedFiles`